# Composer: The checksum verification of the file failed

Tags: composer-php, satis

I am hosting my own Satis repository via GitLab pages.

For some reason however, it keeps on erroring with `The checksum verification of the file failed` when composer tries to install one of the repositories.

Its happening on and off for a few weeks now, and I can't work out why its happening or how to debug it.

Here is my `satis.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Composer Repository",
  "homepage": "<snip>",
  "repositories": [
    {"type": "vcs", "url": "<snip>"},
    {"type": "vcs", "url": "<snip>"}
  ],
  "require-all": true,
  "require-dependencies": true,
  "archive": {
    "directory": "dist",
    "format": "zip",
    "skip-dev": true,
    "checksum": false
  }
}
```

I added `checksum: false` a week ago which seemed to fix the issue, but now it has just arrived again.

I've tried clearing caches and nothing is working. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey James, did you ever find a solution to that?

Comment: I stopped using GitLab Pages and it resolved the issue

Comment: I am using bitbucket and I am not sure if it has anything to do with that.